# Only seeing the wrong AirPlay device

Tags: appletv, airplay

I'm in a hotel equipped with Apple TVs and I can see my neighbor's Apple TV on AirPlay. I cannot, however, see the Apple TV in my own room. I went through the Apple TV settings and performed the following steps:

1. Double checked the network: both my MacBook and the Apple TV are on the same wireless network with a strong signal.
2. Confirmed Apple TV configuration:

   - **AirPlay** On
   - **Conference Room Display** Off
   - **Play from iTunes in the Cloud** Off
   - **Apple TV Name** Apple TV 808
   - **Security** Off
3. Restarted the Apple TV via **Settings > General > Restart**

But I can still only see my neighbor's Apple TV in the AirPlay Selector on my MacBook:

[image: AirPlay Selector]

What, if any, further debugging steps can I try?

Comment: I was going to say change the room, but that is not a alternative? maybe this will help http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5517

Comment: and this could be of help http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4546

Answer (score -1):

I don't have an Apple TV in front of me to direct you to the exact place for this, but I'd trouble-shoot this like any networking discovery issue. Make sure your computer's subnet and the subnet of your Apple TV are the same. The hotel may have it configured strangely.

To get your computer's subnet go to `System Preferences > Network > Wifi` and click the **Advanced** button then go to the **TCP/IP** tab. Your *Subtnet Mask* is shown there and it should match the one the Apple TV is using.

Also (if possible) try and ensure your Apple TV and your Mac are both updated to the latest software available. Apple's support pages also recommend resetting the Apple TV, but I understand that may not be possible in a hotel.

Honestly your best bet is to contact the hotel front desk, since they will be able to do more advanced resets if needed and change the subnet as well.